# What is the prefecture, city and town emblem called?

Tags: word-requests

Prefectures, cities and towns have a seal/emblem associated with them. I have found the terms on JA Wikipedia to describe the flags, but not the term to describe the emblems. Thank you.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because a quick sight on every other article (of Japanese Wikipedia) about a Japan city/prefecture has the answers you are looking for.

Comment: 道理百遍義理一遍 , I will access the Wikipedia as I do not read Japanese fluently, however, I did not find the answer by doing a site search.
@

Comment: Your right the question was not asked earlier but it is easy to get : there are pictures just besides the word you are looking for.

Comment: @道理百遍義理一遍, I mistakenly searched seal/emblem. It is in fact a logo.

Comment: For example, for Kyoto http://imgur.com/a/BZj4e . I am not against answering your questions but you should dig a bit on your side too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

'章' is the kanji for such emblems, like [都道府県章](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E9%83%BD%E9%81%93%E5%BA%9C%E7%9C%8C%E7%AB%A0) for prefectures, 市章 for cities, and so on. 国章 is used to refer to national coat of arms. To give a specific example, we have 京都市章 for the city of Kyoto, as mentioned by  道理百遍義理一遍.

*Emblems* or *coat of arms* in general is 紋章 in Japanese (As far as I know, we don't have specific words to distinguish emblems and coat of arms).
So 「京都市の紋章」 *the emblem of Kyoto city* is another (more descriptive) expression, and is actually [used by the city of Kyoto](http://www.city.kyoto.lg.jp/sogo/page/0000015587.html).
As a side note, Heraldry is 紋章学.

Comment: I honestly think looking up any large English-Japanese dictionary for English speakers would have answered, thus making this off-topic, but I am not certain about the availability of such dictionaries (as an *English* learner, on the other hand, we have plenty of good dictionaries). Looking for the actual emblems first and finding out how they are described seemed a little tricky for me.